# Permission issue with creating a dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am still in the beginning stages of using BigQuery and also completing my certificate in Data Analytics. I have reached out to several resources with no resolution yet.

Im getting the following message when creating a dataset in BigQuery:

You must have the "bigquery.datasets.create" permission on the selected project

I have a sandbox free Bigquery account and I tried following the steps to gain the necessary permission but i am still at a loss to resolve my issue

Comment: please check the IAM google service

Answer (score 0):

Apparently being an Owner doesn't give you access to much. So you need to go to IAM, create a custom role with access to BigQuery resources (mainly bigquery.datasets.create) and then assign that role to your email in addition to Owner.